# Method return if Java 8's Optional is present

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, return, option-type

In Java 8, is there a way to force a method return if an `Optional` is present?
I would guess that the answer is no. But then how to avoid using `isPresent()` and `get()` in the following code?

```java
public Bar myMethod(){
    if(condition){
        Optional<Foo> foo = getOptionalFoo();
        if(foo.isPresent()){
            return foo.get().getBar();
        }
    }

    return getOtherBar();
}
```

One solution would be to write :

```
public Bar myMethod(){
    if(condition){
        return getOptionalFoo()
                .map(Foo::getBar)
                .orElseGet(() -> getOtherBar());
    }

    return getOtherBar();
}
```

But it doesn't seem like a good idea because now we write twice the call to `getOtherBar`. Is there a way to avoid this?

EDIT: I also thought of

```
public Bar myMethod(){
    //Or a ternary operator but there are hard to read when they make long lines
    Optional<Foo> foo;
    if(condition){
        foo = getOptionalFoo();
    } else {
        foo = Optional.empty();
    }

    return foo.map(Foo::getBar)
        .orElseGet(() -> getOtherBar());
}
```

But the issue here is that we create a useless empty `Optional` and chain methods to it. If the condition is not met 99% of the time, this make it quite less efficient than the original code (especially if we have several `map()` and `filter()`).

NOTE: I gave a basic example, in reality in our code we have more conditions that depend on the results of other calls (which depend of foo).

Comment: There is no difference to the compiler between these two methods. You can't have both of these in an application

Comment: @rabbitguy I don't understand your statement

Answer (score 3):

How about this? the form of the code below is more **readable** but it is **slower** than yours, since if the `condition` is not satisfied, `getOtherBar()` also need additional operations (`map` & `orElseGet`) on  an `Optional`.

```
public Bar myMethod() {
    Optional<Foo> source = condition ? getFoo() : Optional.empty();

    return source.map(Foo::getBar)
                 .orElseGet(this::getOtherBar);
}
```

However, if there are a lot of duplications likes as above, then you can free yourself by extract a method, for example:

```
private Optional<Foo> foo(){
    return  condition ? getFoo() : Optional.empty();
}

public Bar myMethod() {
    return foo().map(Foo::getBar).orElseGet(this::getOtherBar);
}

public Other otherMethod() {
    return foo().map(Foo::getOther).orElseGet(this::getOther);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What is `condition`? Since it’s located in an instance method, it must be a condition depending on the state of the instance. For simplicity, assume that this is a field of your class, then you could write

```
public Bar myMethod() {
    return Optional.of(this)
        .filter(obj -> obj.condition)
        .flatMap(ClassContainingMyMethod::getFoo)
        .map(Foo::getBar)
        .orElseGet(this::getOtherBar);
}
```

If `getFoo()` is not expensive and has no side effects, you could accept calling it always, even if you’re not going to use its result, depending on `condition`. Which would simplify the code to

```
public Bar myMethod() {
    return getFoo()
        .filter(foo -> condition)
        .map(Foo::getBar)
        .orElseGet(this::getOtherBar);
}
```

Note that there is a semantic difference to your original code. When `getBar` returns `null`, the original code returns `null`, whereas all code using `Optional.map` with a function returning the result of `getBar()` will fall back to calling `getOtherBar()`.

Comment: The example I provided is a really simplified example of what we encountered. The real method is more complicated than that and we actually had several if conditions.

I'm not a fan of this because if the condition only depends on the parameters of the method, it would we confusing for the reader to read `Optional.of(this) .filter(obj -> conditionThatDoesNotDependOnTheInstance)`

Some for filtering ´foo´ with a condition that doesn't depend of it.

Comment: @Ricola: then, you oversimplified your example. That’s exactly the reason why I made it a question, “What is `condition`?”. If it is a condition of a parameter, you could use `Optional.of(parameter) .filter(predicateOfParameter)` instead. If you are combining several parameters into a condition or have even more complex stuff, refactor the entire conditional code into a single `boolean` returning method or, if that’s not possible, stay with an `if` statement that works much better with complex conditions. Lambda expressions are intended for (and work best with) small piece of code only.

Comment: I think your last sentence is actually the real answer to my question.

" Lambda expressions are intended for (and work best with) small piece of code only."

I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This falls together pretty easily once you get into the `Optional` mindset, and use a ternary operator to handle your condition.

```
public Bar myMethod(){
    return ( condition ? getOptionalFoo() : Optional.<Foo> empty())
         .map(f -> f.getBar())
         .orElseGet(() -> getOtherBar())
}
```